# How is it possible to connect my network to another network?

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking

Not sure how to google this one...

How is it possible to connect my network to another network?

Here is my setup:

Network 1:
I currently have a laptop with Windows 7

and a server with Windows Server 2008 R2, which is setup as a Domain Controller, DNS, Web Server and SQL Server

Network 2:
Desktop with Windows XP 

Server with Windows Server 2008 R2, which is also setup as a Domain Controller and DNS server

What would I need to get the 2 networks together, they are both at seperate locations, different ISPs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using VPN (Virtual Private Network).

You can get these two networks be as a single network with VPN. You can even access the PCs / servers at the other network using their private IPs.

There are many options for creating a VPN like PPTP / IPSec.

Comment: Thanks, was thinking VPN but wasn't positive